# error while registering bower package: "EUNKNOWN Unknown error: 403"

Tags: registration, bower

I'm trying to register a bower package (jhudson8/reactbone.git) and am getting the error (listed in the title).  I have created a github release with the version identified in bower..json.

```
bower register reactbone git://github.com/jhudson8/reactbone.git
bower reactbone#*              resolve git://github.com/jhudson8/reactbone.git#*
bower reactbone#*             download https://github.com/jhudson8/reactbone/archive/v0.6.1.tar.gz
bower reactbone#*              extract archive.tar.gz
bower reactbone#*             resolved git://github.com/jhudson8/reactbone.git#0.6.1
[?] Registering a package will make it installable via the registry (https://bower.herokuapp.com), continue? Yes
bower reactbone               register git://github.com/jhudson8/reactbone.git
bower                         EUNKNOWN Unknown error: 403
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.  thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting a `console.log(response.body)` statement [right around here](https://github.com/bower/registry-client/blob/47e6232fc67e9c5cace371aff64e3928012522e3/lib/register.js#L48-L50), gives the following

[`Package already registered`](http://bower.io/search/?q=reactbone)